# How print two times same random number?

Tags: python, windows, math, random, console

I try to make a code that prints two equal random values in a text.

```
import random
archivo=open('Ejercicio3.txt', 'w')
up=0
insert=int(input('Valor: '))
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    n1=random.randint(10, 100)
    n2=random.randint(10, 100)
    archivo.write(f'{up}.-    {n1} - {n2} = {n1-n2}\n\n')

    print(f'{up}.-    {n1} - {n2} = {n1-n2}')
    archivo.write(f'{n1-n2}\n')#This is the problem, because the code write numbers different random

archivo.close()
```

What I want is for it to do something similar to this:

```
import random
archivo=open('Ejercicio1.1.txt', 'w')
up=0
insert=int(input('Valor: '))
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    n1=random.randint(10, 100)
    n2=random.randint(10, 100)

    archivo.write(f'{n1} - {n2} =''\n\n')

up=0
archivo.write('---------------------------------------------\n')
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    n1=random.randint(10, 100)
    n2=random.randint(10, 100)
    archivo.write(f'{n1-n2}''\n\n')#Except this part, I want it to be exactly the same as the result of the subtraction above. 
archivo.close()
```

The result i want, is this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKLiA.png)

Someone can I help me? Thanks very much. Regards

Comment: "two equal random values" ... what? You mean print two times same random number?

Comment: Yes, print two times same random number

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez then use `n1` 2 times and remove `n2`.

Comment: @AlbinPaul if I remove n2, I will not be able to do the addition or subtraction operation.

Comment: its `n1` - `n1` .right?  what is your objective?

Comment: @AlbinPaul its n1 - n2. The result has to go in a line break.

Comment: @AlbinPaul example [Example image](https://imgur.com/vt3Zc0m.jpg)

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez I understand now. Just store the results of the subtraction in a list and then iterate over them again.

Comment: You just need to initialize Seed with the same value before each for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the results in a list and then iterate over it again.

```
import random
archivo=open('Ejercicio1.1.txt', 'w')
up=0
results = []
insert=int(input('Valor: '))
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    n1=random.randint(10, 100)
    n2=random.randint(10, 100)
    results.append(n1-n2)
    archivo.write(f'{n1} - {n2} = {n1 - n2} ''\n\n')

up=0
archivo.write('---------------------------------------------\n')
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    archivo.write(f'{results[i]}''\n\n')
archivo.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `random.seed()` and set the same seed two times.

```
import random

random.seed(0)
print(random.random())
#prints a random number    

random.seed(0)
print(random.random())
#prints the same random number
```